# Should I use a road bike or track bike on my rollers or trainer?

Tags: training, trainer, rollers, indoor

I have a road bike with a triple, a track bike with a high gear ratio.  Which should I use on my trainer for use with training videos?  Should I use a geared bike, freewheel single speed or fixed gear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bike to use will depend on the reason for using the trainer. If your use of the trainer is for off season track training use the track bike, road racing  use the triple,etc. If you just want some saddle time, the triple will simulate all of them to an extent, you can select the gearing of the track bike,the fixie or the single and leave it there.

Comment: I don't think the road bike will give the same feel as the track bike at the same gear ratio, mostly because of the difference between the freewheel and fixed gear drivetrain.

I think I prefer the triple road bike due on the rollers since I have more options for the gearing to change resistance on the rollers, depending on my activity.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. You've thrown out a few options. I'm a track cyclist, so I prefer the track bike on the rollers. However, that's mostly to work on form and comfort at high RPM's in my race position. That's the main benefit of rollers.

For strength training and resistance, I used to use a mag or fluid trainer. I would do so with a road bike. The main benefit there is the ability to change gears/resistance by shifting. That would be more appropriate if you're looking to ride along with a video...

Nowadays, I take a [completely different ($$$) approach](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ewwhite/8050847367/in/photostream)...